# How to extract different variables from a regex without compiling each expression

Tags: regex, go

I have a struct representing sizes of computer objects. Objects of this struct are constructed from string values input by users; e.g. "50KB" would be tokenised into an int value of "50" and the string value "KB".

```
type SizeUnit string

const (
    B  = "B"
    KB = "KB"
    MB = "MB"
    GB = "GB"
    TB = "TB"
)

type ObjectSize struct {
    NumberOfUnits int
    Unit          SizeUnit
}

func NewObjectSizeFromString(input_str string) (*ObjectSize, error)
```

In the body of this function, I first check if the input value is in the valid format; i.e. any number of digits, followed by any one of "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" or "TB". I then extract the int and string components separately and return a pointer to a struct.

In order to do these three things though, I'm having to compile the regex three times.
The first time to check the format of the input string

```
rg, err := regexp.Compile(`^[0-9]+B$|KB$|MB$|GB$|TB$`)
```

And then compile again to fetch the int component:

```
rg, err := regexp.Compile(`^[0-9]+`)
rg.FindString(input_str)
```

And then compile again to fetch the string/units component:

```
rg, err := regexp.Compile(`B$|KB$|MB$|GB$|TB$`)
rg.FindString(input_str)
```

Is there any way to get the two components from the input string with a single regex compilation?

The full code can be found on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fSav0bZUaYY).

I should point out that this is an academic question as I'm experimenting with Go's regex library. For a simple use-case of this sort, I would probably use a simple for loop to parse the input string.

Comment: Use capturing groups, `^([0-9]+)([KMGT]?B)$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture both the values with a single expression using [`regexp.FindStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch):

```golang
func NewObjectSizeFromString(input_str string) (*ObjectSize, error) {
    var defaultReturn *ObjectSize = nil
    full_search_pattern := `^([0-9]+)([KMGT]?B)$`

    rg, err := regexp.Compile(full_search_pattern)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultReturn, errors.New("Could not compile search expression")
    }
    matched := rg.FindStringSubmatch(input_str)
    if matched ==  nil {
        return defaultReturn, errors.New("Not in valid format")
    }
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(matched[1], 10, 32)
    return &ObjectSize{int(i), SizeUnit(matched[2])}, nil
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K5wUWHoxmhE).

The `^([0-9]+)([KMGT]?B)$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 (this value will be held in `matched[1]`): one or more digits
- `([KMGT]?B)` - Group 2 (it will be in `matched[2]`): an optional `K`, `M`, `G`, `T` letter, and then a `B` letter
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `matched[0]` will hold the whole match.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. I had tried FindStringSubmatch earlier but I must admit I didn't really understand how to use it.And unfortunately I did not find the function [help](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) to be very descriptive either. But your example makes it very clear, thank again!